# OpenVPN disallow clients talking to each other but allow traffic to server host

Tags: iptables, vpn, firewall, routing, openvpn

I am using the *client-to-client* configuration option to allow clients to reach out to the VPN host over it's internal IP address but I would like to prevent clients from reaching out to each other.

Subnet:
172.16.12.0/22

Clients communicate with the server over 172.16.12.1.

Answer (score 0):

*client-to-client* directive allows to keep all the routing logic inside virtual OpenVPN network.

If you disable it (just remove it in the config) the clients should be able to reach 172.16.12.1 but not each other.